# How to refer to the parent in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to do this:

```
//x[//y[@a = @b]]
```

I need to find all elements `<x>`, which have `<y>` somewhere in the document, such that `x/@a = y/@b`. Obviously, my code is wrong. How to show that `@a` belongs to `x` and `@b` belongs to `y`?

Comment: Do you mean: Find all elements with tag name `x` and attribute `a` such as there are some other elements, with tag name `y` and attribute `b` where the value of attribute `a` in element `x` equals to the value of attribute `b` in element `y` ?

Comment: @Prophet yes, exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the literal title question (*How to refer to the parent in XPath?*), the answer would be to use the `parent::` axis or its abbreviation (`..`).  However, that's not actually needed to achieve the requested outcome here.

This XPath,

```
//x[@a = //y/@b]
```

will select all `x` elements with an `a` attribute value that equals some `y` element's `b` attribute value anywhere in the document.

Comment: Will this work if I replace `=` with `!=` in the task definition?

Comment: @yegor256: It will *work* for some definition of *work*.  It will probably not do what I suspect you'd want: If you want to select those `x` elements that were not selected by the original XPath, instead use `//x[not(@a = //y/@b)]`